# is it possible to close a div containing another html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

is it possible to close or empty the div containing an html? and the code where you want to close/empty the div is in the html. my div is a pop up.

like this.

```
<div id="n_test">
    <object data="test.php">
     #document
     <html>......
     the code that empty the id="n_test"
     </html>
   </object>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like you are copying code from devtools. That's an `iframe`

Comment: actually it's an object tag . that calls a php

Comment: why give me a down vote?

Comment: That markup would not be valid: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html

Comment: @JerahmeelAcebuche who said I downvoted you?

Comment: @AhmadAlfy no sorry. it's not you.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use `has` selector in jquery ,Do not use html...... inside div tag

### HTML

```
 <div id="n_test">
     #document
     <ifame>......
     the code that empty the id="n_test"
     </ifame>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#n_test").has("ifame").hide();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/58a9P/5/)

Comment: where should i put the script? inside the another html/ inner html?

Comment: @JerahmeelAcebuche sorry, that is invalid html ,The html tag should not inside any tag element , you have to use any other tags like ifrmae or some others

Comment: @Downvoter could you tel me the reason for downvote?